# BroadcastReceiver autostart enable

Tags: android

I wrote a class Autostart that extends BroadcastReceiver. This starts at every reboot of android. Within this class there're some intents and alarmmanager. Everything runs perfectly. Now I added "preference" to enable/disable this class. The problem is: when I disable this class (using IF/ELSE), and later enable it, I must restart mobile.

**How resolve this problem?**

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

Calendar cal1 = Calendar.getInstance();
[...]

Intent intent2 = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
[...]

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
[...]
```

Comment: You can check the preference in `onRecieve()` and just do nothing if preference is set to disable. Also, use another custom defined broadcast that let you trigger this code on demand. (when you enable)

Comment: Ok thanks, I see: public abstract void onReceive (Context context, Intent intent). Can I have an example? thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem is: when I disable this class (using IF/ELSE), and later enable it, I must restart mobile.

Move your code that you execute on boot into a static method somewhere. Call that code both from the boot-time `BroadcastReceiver` and from your "enable this logic" code path.

Comment: mhmhm...so, I need create another BroadcastReceiver and put it this code?

Comment: @PolHallen: Probably not. My answer certainly does not say that. A "static method" is not a `BroadcastReceiver`. You already *have* a `BroadcastReceiver` ("a class Autostart that extends BroadcastReceiver"). You simply need to have the *business logic* of that `BroadcastReceiver` be accessible elsewhere, and in most cases a simple solution for this is to move the contents of your `onReceive()` method into a static method that `onReceive()` calls (and can be called from elsewhere).

Comment: Ok, I understood your words, by theory line, thanks. But in the line practice how do it? Can I've an example please? thanks!

Comment: @PolHallen: If you do not know what a static method is in Java, please read http://www.leepoint.net/notes-java/flow/methods/50static-methods.html or use your favorite search engine to find other Java educational resources.

Comment: I known static method. Thanks.

Comment: I tried to move that code to MainActivity with a static method by I've some problems. Can you help me please?

Comment: @PolHallen: Here is a sample application that shows a static method being used by both an activity and a boot-time `BroadcastReceiver`: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AlarmManager/Scheduled

Comment: Thanks for the link. In your code I see alarmmanager and intents on the PollReceiver (that extends BroadcastReceiver) like my code with also "static void onReceive). So, I don't need move my code to other class, or something wrong? Be patience... I studying.

Comment: @PolHallen: At this point, you should perhaps consider finding support from a site that is in a language that is more comfortable for you: http://www.andglobe.com. The point behind my link in my previous comment was to show you sample code of a boot-time `BroadcastReceiver` and something else (in this case, an `Activity`) both using a static method for their work (in this case, scheduling alarms). If you want to not "restart mobile", you will have to do the work that you normally do when you "restart mobile" from some other place, and this is an example. I cannot help you further.